# Allowing cross domain request to Delicious feed from Angular.js

Tags: javascript, angularjs, cors, delicious-api

I'm trying to get Delicious count with their feed with angularJs. In my previous code, simple jquery works, but with angular I get error

```
No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.
```

This is due to newer libraries [CORS](http://www.w3.org/TR/cors/)

This is jquery fiddle: http://jsbin.com/iVufAHuf/1/edit

This is angular fiddle: http://jsbin.com/OQUsuDuC/1/edit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use

```
$http.jsonp
```

with correct callback syntax in url params. See.

http://jsbin.com/EFeXuNap/2/edit

Comment: I have tested with dataType: 'jsonp', and not worked. So there is a difference between $http.jsonp and dataType: 'jsonp'? However thanks for the answer.

Comment: You had a little problem in Syntax. "success" is not a function passed in the config object, rather a prototype of the http which is shown here http://jsbin.com/iNadAmAb/1/edit